# What stats are best suited to a shortbow/longbow weilding Ranger?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, like any other MMO, there are a variety of stats including the basics such as 'Vitality', 'Armour' and 'Critical Chance'. There are also some more unique ones that don't normally appear in MMOs like 'Condition Damage', 'Precision', etc.

I am currently playing a Ranger, and I use short bows and long bows. I am also in the process of creating myself some exotic gear using the Leatherworking crafting discipline, so I was wondering what stats would most benefit a Ranger playing with bows?

Comment: How are you building trait wise? Longbow is a Power-based weapon, while Shortbow has a lot of conditions. Gear choice should be dictated by *spec*, not weapon choice alone.

Comment: There was an interesting post on reddit a while back (I would find it for you however the reddit search function is awful) about just this subject. It also had some nice math showing when it was best to use a short/longbow. If you can brave the reddit search feature I would recommend finding it.

Comment: @AdamP   http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/13ryxb/shortbow_vs_longbow_damage_outputs_ranger_data/ may be the post you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built my Ranger on a 'Glass Cannon' spec, built around bleeding as a condition, with matching traits.

I've stacked Power, Precision and Condition Damage as my primary stats.

[I detailed my thoughts on my blog](http://neon1024.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/guild-wars-2-ranger-build/).